# 12.04 does not detect eth0(Atheros AR8162 )

Tags: 12.04, atheros, ethernet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get an Atheros AR8162 working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205582/how-do-i-get-an-atheros-ar8162-working)

Installed 12.04 on dell inspiron 5420. WiFi is working however wired connection does not work. In fact I can't see eth0. Can I know the correct driver to install?