# Ethernet not working on a Dell Inspiron 14z

Tags: dell, ethernet, inspiron

When I plug in a network cable, it is not recognized. The WI-FI is working properly, though.

`ifconfig` output:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1645 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1645 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:206840 (206.8 KB)  TX bytes:206840 (206.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:06:e6:de:57:e7  
          inet addr:150.164.201.145  Bcast:150.164.201.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2001:12f0:601:a921:98a2:3dd:3be8:c483/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2001:12f0:601:a921:e206:e6ff:fede:57e7/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::e206:e6ff:fede:57e7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:23892 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14676 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30123226 (30.1 MB)  TX bytes:2189050 (2.1 MB)
```

Comment: try `dhclient eth0` and see if it works.

Comment: I got the message: "Cannot find device "eth0" "

Comment: post the output of `ifconfig`

Comment: @green7 edited the question with that info.

Comment: what about `ifconfig -a`. Do you see something like `eth0` of `eth1` or something similar.

Comment: you might want to continue this discussion on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4746/chat-between-green7-and-x).

Comment: ifconfig -a shows the same info, no eth0 or eth1.
I will log in to be able to chat.

Comment: Run `lspci | grep Ethernet`. If you don't see anything, run `lspci` and look for anything that seems like ethernet card. Or better post the output.

Comment: 09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the drivers from this website: http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/.

If you're not sure which one to select, download this one: http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-09-05-pc.tar.bz2.

First run `sudo su` and enter your password when prompted.

Then, follow these steps:

```
tar xjf compat-wireless-2012-09-05-pc.tar.bz2
cd compat-wireless-2012-09-05-pc
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
make install
modprobe alx
```

Reboot.

*It might seem misleading to download the drivers because of the name, but give it a shot.*

Comment: I will love to change the negative into an upvote if it works to the OP or if you give some reference or explanation about how does it work and why.

Comment: It worked!!!

Just a note to someone following this thread: I had a permission problem, so remember to 'sudo'. 
Thank you @green7.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you find it as correct. And also please tell where did you use `sudo` so that I can correct it.

Comment: The first time it did not work, if I remember well, it had a permission problem in ./scripts/driver-select alx. So I used "sudo su" and did the entire process again...

Comment: I'll update the answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Ubuntu 12.10 with Inspiron 14z), just installing the linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic package solved the problem.  Here's the magic command:

sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic

*p.s.:  This seems to be a duplicate of:  [12.04 does not detect eth0(Atheros AR8162 )](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157223/12-04-does-not-detect-eth0atheros-ar8162/231715#231715)*

Comment: I tried to install the package above but got the following message:
  E: Unable to locate package linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic
  E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic'