# Is hardware support for the Lenovo G580 laptop really that bad?

Tags: drivers, hardware

I am planing to buy a Lenovo G580 (59-324061) laptop. I found it is the best laptop in that price range. However, if I Google it for support in Ubuntu, I see many people complaining about driver problems with Ubuntu 12.04. I've read about wired network problems and brightness control issues with Ubuntu 12.04.

Is it really that bad?

Comment: Did you buy this laptop finally? If yes how did it turn out?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 and everything except of camera works. The camera sometimes works too, but only in VLC. But worth to note that there are many versions of G580 with quite different configuration. Even motherboard can differ. Mine is with Core i3 and wifi Atheros.

Answer (score 2):

The driver problem for the Atheros AR8162 network card in the Lenovo G580 was solved in the latest Ubuntu 12.04 point release (12.04.2, 14 Feb 2013). The [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) introduced in that release will pull in Linux kernel 3.5.0 from Quantal, which has built-in support for the alx driver.

For those currently on 12.04: updating to 12.04.2 will *not* automatically enable the LTS Enablement Stack. You must install the package **linux-generic-lts-quantal** to do that.

Comment: In Ubuntu 13.10 there is no problem with wifi.

Answer (score 1):

I have been the same problem. This pc works very good... I will try with this http://www.zyxware.com/articles/2680/solved-wired-connection-eth0-not-detected-in-ubuntu-12-04

(If doesn't work I will try with OpenSUSE.)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I just purchased this computer.  I have everything working but brightness controls.    Ethernet connection will not work upon install.

I found [this Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157223/12-04-does-not-detect-eth0atheros-ar8162) with useful information that worked for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Is your camera working? For me it doesn't work in Skype. Do you know why? http://askubuntu.com/questions/296330/ubuntu-13-04-on-lenovo-g580-built-in-webcam-not-recognized (Ubuntu 13.10)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the brightness controls, the only major trouble I have (and it's a big one for me) is that sound input is intermittently distorted when I use Jack. I don't use an ethernet connection, but both wireless and USB tethering are fine.